# Summing lists elements using zip

Tags: python, list

I am trying to sum up lists vertically but facing below issues.
Example 1 below shows the sample how I need the output as.
Example 2 below shows the problem I am facing.

**Example 1:**

```
list1 = [111]
list2 = [222]
sum_list = []

for (item1, item2) in zip(list1, list2):
    sum_list.append(item1+item2)

print(sum_list)    # [333]
```

**Example 2:**

```
inp = "1111 2222"
list1 = inp.split()
#print(list1)
list2 = [int(i) for i in list1]
print(list2)   # [1111, 2222]
out = [sum(item) for item in zip(list2)]

print(out)   # [1111, 2222]
```

I need the out as [3333] (as mentioned like Example 1 above) but it is printing as [1111, 2222].

Comment: Zip takes multiple iterators e.g. A, B, C and zips them together as (A1, B1, C1), then (A2, B2, C2) and so on. You are only passing it a single iterator, so the output is just A1 then A2.

Comment: Why do you need `zip` for a single list? `sum(map(int, inp.split()))`

Comment: Why `zip`? How about `out = [sum(list2)]`?

Comment: It's unclear what you expect the behaviour to be more generally, e.g. if input was `"1 2 3 4 5"`, what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just sum list2 and put it inside an array.

```
inp = "1111 2222"
list1 = inp.split()
list2 = [int(i) for i in list1]
print(list2) # [1111, 2222]
out = [sum(list2)]

print(out)   # [333]
```